# Rendering components from an Object instead of endless comparing

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to replace this kind of code:

```
    {component === 'Benchmark' && <Benchmark />}
    {component === 'DiskSpace' && <DiskSpace />}
    {component === 'MainFeature' && <MainFeature />}
    {component === 'Scanning' && <Scanning />}
    {component === 'Uninstaller' && <Uninstaller />}
```

With an object like so:

```
const components = {
  Benchmark: Benchmark,
  DiskSpace: DiskSpace,
  MainFeature: MainFeature,
  Scanning: Scanning,
  Uninstaller: Uninstaller,
}
```

So that I can do:

```
export const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = ({ component, title, backgroundImg, ...props }) => {
  const Component = components[component]

  return (
    <CardContainer {...props}>
        <Component />
    </CardContainer>
  )
}
```

In both cases components are being imported the same way, no change in the way I am importing them at all.

The first way with the `===` and `&&` is working just fine, however the second way throws errors:

When building:

```
  ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Benchmark' before initialization
```

When running and trying to render:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for 
built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed 
up default and named imports.
```

But these exact same imports work with the first kind of code, so how could it be importing issue!

Also I have the exact same pattern in another part of my app, and its working just fine there.

Logging the `components` object gives everything as `undefined` `console.log(components);`:

```
{
  Benchmark: undefined,
  DiskSpace: undefined,
  MainFeature: undefined,
  Scanning: undefined,
  Uninstaller: undefined
}
```

Logging an individual component `console.log(Benchmark);` works just fine:

```
[Function: Benchmark]
```

I just figured that if I put it within the component it works:

```
export const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = ({ component, title, backgroundImg, ...props }) => {
  const components = {
    Benchmark: Benchmark,
    DiskSpace: DiskSpace,
    MainFeature: MainFeature,
    Scanning: Scanning,
    Uninstaller: Uninstaller,
  }

  const Component = components[component]

  return (
    <CardContainer {...props}>
      {backgroundImg && <CardBackgroundImg {...backgroundImg} />}
      <CardTitle value={title} />
      <CardContents>{Component && <Component />}</CardContents>
    </CardContainer>
  )
}
```

^ This works, however, I want the components object to be outside of the component, and as I have already mentioned, I have that exact same pattern used for rendering the sections on my page and it works just fine, with the `components` section outside of the component that is being rendered.

Comment: I would try to pass a JSX object instead of a "dictionary" of components... and the caller decide what component to pass... the confusion seems between a "type" and an "instance".